# unzip | caution: filename not matched

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I'm trying to unzip multiple files which has a prefix in common **service1.zip** **service-2.zip** **service_3.zip** and so on...

Now, when I try to unzip all those files at once using the command `unzip service*.zip` I'm getting an error which says `caution: filename not matched: service.zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there are special characters in the file names and bash misunderstands while expanding that command.

To avoid this error:

**solution-1**: use the command within **''** `unzip 'service*.zip'`
**solution-2**: pass the file name with **\** to escape special characters `unzip service\\*.zip`